# JSP formatting vs date issue

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, jstl

I have the following code in my jsp. I use JSTL `${scheduledRideEndTime}` to retrieve the data.

```
<script>
    var timeto2 = ${scheduledRideEndTime};
    var hours3 = moment(timeto2).format("hh:mm a")
    document.write(hours3);
</script>
```

If I hit `Control Shift F` on eclipse the formatting changes to

```
 <script>
    var timeto2 = $
    {
         scheduledRideEndTime
    };
    var hours3 = moment(timeto2).format("hh:mm a")
    document.write(hours3);
</script>
```

I then get syntax errors in my view. If I redo the code to `"${scheduledRideEndTime}";` the `Control Shift F` does not reformat the code, but view prints `Invalid date`.

What am I missing here ? I want to be able to reformat code.

Comment: maybe try to wrap it in single quotes? `'${scheduledRideEndTime}'`

Comment: i think not the best way but , load the value in dom or some hidden field like `$("#abc").val("${scheduledRideEndTime}")` and then get the value next time , i have done something like this before `$("#voucherNumber").val(
     "${sessionScope.abc}");` and get it

Comment: @JapanGuy single quotes did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var timeto2 = parseInt("${scheduledRideEndTime}");
    var hours3 = moment(timeto2).format("hh:mm a")
    document.write(hours3);
</script>
```